# Writing an algorithm for matrix

Tags: matrices, algorithms, schemes

I've been given a task to write an algorithm and it's scheme and, honestly, I'm really stuck, don't know steps i need to take firstly. All I'm asking is to put me on a road to solve this.

The task is : There is $n \times n$ matrix. You need to find how many positive elements are there over the diagonal and then find their sum and average.

Comment: One approach would be to do the count and sum of positive entries in the first row (your specification is unclear whether diagonal elements are included), then remove the first row and first column.  Repeat the counting and summing until you've reduced the matrix to size $1\times 1$.  It may be difficult for Readers to help with your exercise, which is more of a programming problem than a math problem.

Comment: You don't even tell us which data structure you're considering to store the matrix...

Comment: search for the values where $i=j$.

Answer (score 0):

If we suppose that your matrix $A$ is indexed by row and columns with $A_{ij}$ the element with row $i$ and column $j$, then the elements over the diagonal are the ones such that $j \geq i$.

You can do a two nested loops with $i$ from $1$ to $n$ and then $j$ from $i$ to $n$.

For example, in pseudo-code, to compute the sum of all elements over the diagonal if $A_{ij}$ is accessed by A[i,j]:

```
sum = 0
for i from 1 to n
    for j from i to n
        sum = sum + A[i,j]
    endfor
endfor
```